# Sample size to detect decrease in standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

Running into a little bit of an issue with an experiment.

Basically, I'd like to make a change in a process that may or may not reduce the variation in production. The mean value of the process is of no consequence, only the variation.

My experience with stats is quite limited, and what I can find so far are only processes for calculating sample sizes for hypothesis tests for a difference of means between groups, not the standard deviations between the groups.

What's the best way to go about calculating this? I'm certain I'm not the first person to want to do such a thing, but I think I'm simply calling it the wrong thing and/or using the wrong search terms.

Comment: What statistical test will you prepare to use after you finish your data collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The F Test

As a point of departure, suppose each experiment obtains samples of independent observations.  Let the first experiment obtain $n$ observations from a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution and the second obtain $m$ observations from a Normal$(\mu^\prime, \tau^2)$ distribution.  The null hypothesis is

$$H_0:\ \tau^2 = \sigma^2$$

while the alternative is that there is some $0\le \rho \lt 1$ (the "effect size," giving the new standard deviation as a proportion of the old) and

$$H_\text{A}: \tau^2  = \rho^2 \sigma^2.$$

Under the null, the sample variances $s_\text{first}^2$ and $s_\text{second}^2$ have $\chi^2$ distributions with $n-1$ and $m-1$ degrees of freedom, respectively, scaled by the common variance $\sigma^2.$  A likelihood ratio test is based on the F ratio statistic

$$F = \frac{s_\text{second}^2}{s_\text{first}^2}.$$

Under the null hypothesis the common variances cancel and (therefore) $F$ has an F ratio distribution with $m-1, n-1$ degrees of freedom, written $F_{m-1,n-1}.$  Under the alternative hypothesis this ratio will tend to be less than $1.$  Thus, a critical region of size $\alpha$ is the set of all possible ratios less than the $100\alpha$ percentile of $F_{m-1,n-1},$ written $F_{m-1,n-1}^{-1}(\alpha).$  This is the test you will eventually use to determine whether the standard deviation has decreased.

---

#### Sample Size Determination

**Determining a sample size** requires specifying how much of an effect $\rho$ you want to be able to detect and what chance you want of detecting it (the "power", or $1-\beta$).  When the effect is $\rho,$ then the F ratio statistic will be multiplied by $\rho^2.$  The decrease will be detected whenever $\rho^2 F$ is in the critical region; that is, $\rho^2 F \le \alpha.$  Thus, you will want to take a number of samples $m$ so assure

$$\Pr(\rho^2 F \le \alpha) \ge 1-\beta.$$

[image: Figure showing graphical interpretation of the zeros]

*This figure graphs the density of $F_{m-1,n-1}$ in blue with $n=33$ and $m=12.$  Thus, the horizontal axis represents variance ratios and the vertical axis is proportional to the probability density.  When shrunk by a factor $\rho^2$ towards the vertical axis (represented by the horizontal dotted gray arrows) it becomes the red curve.  ($\rho = 0.62$ in this figure, so $\rho^2=0.38.$)  $\alpha$ (here equal to $0.05$) is the relative area under the blue curve to the left of the critical value $F^{-1}_{m-1,n-1}(\alpha):$ this is the critical region, having only a chance of $\alpha$ under the null hypothesis.  $\beta$ is the relative area under the red curve beyond the critical region (it is around $0.4$ here).  It represents the chance that $F$ will not lie in the critical region when the new standard deviation is $\rho$ times the old one (a "false negative" or "Type II" error).  The power for this combination of sample sizes $n-1,m-1,$ effect size $\rho,$ and test size $\alpha$ is the complementary chance $1-\beta.$*

Because the F ratio distributions are continuous, such $m$ (if they exist) are the zeros of the function

$$m \to F_{m-1,n-1}\left(\rho^2 F_{m-1,n-1}^{-1}(1-\beta)\right) - \alpha.$$

Note that if $n$ is small, it might be impossible to obtain enough new samples to determine with high probability that a small decrease in standard deviation has occurred, because there's no way to reduce the uncertainty in the standard deviation associated with a small initial sample size.

`R` code to find these zeros, in the form of a `sample.size` function, is appended below.  It rounds its solution up to the next integer, because you have to take a whole number of samples!

---

#### Going Beyond Theory: Simulation Results

**Although formulas are nice, it's even better to understand the trade-off between paying for more samples (both before and after), the effect size, and the power.**  This can be studied using the formulas--but only when the original assumptions of Normal distributions apply.  To study possible departures from Normality, a simulation study is usually needed.

I ran simulations of these experiments for six initial sample sizes $n,$ five new sample sizes $m,$ four effect sizes $\rho \lt 1,$ and two other effect sizes in the wrong direction ($\rho=1$ and $\rho=1.1$).  In each simulation I generated 2000 pairs of datasets and tested for a change using the F ratio statistic, retaining the p-value for further study.  This graph plots the empirical distributions of those p-values.  Because decisions are usually made with test sizes of $10\%$ or less, I plot only the p-values in this low range.  All plots are on common scales for comparability.

[image: Figure 1]

Plots that move quickly to the top from the origin show a tendency to produce low p-values: these are where the power is high.  For reference, the distribution of p-values under the null hypothesis is uniform, shown as a straight black line with a slope of 1:1.  (In most cases this line is overplotted by the line of simulated p-values for $\rho=1,$ as it should.)

To help understand this, I used the `sample.size` function to perform sample size calculations for $\beta=0.25$ and $\alpha=0.05$ (shown as the horizontal black black line at $1-0.25=0.75$ and vertical black line at a p-value of $0.05$).  Here is its output.

```
> t(outer(c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160, Inf), c(0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9), sample.size, beta=0.25))
    10 20 40  80 160 Inf
0.6 NA 25 18  16  15  14
0.7 NA NA 49  33  29  25
0.8 NA NA NA 165  87  60
0.9 NA NA NA  NA  NA 252
```

Let's compare this to the graphic.  The first column of "NA" values says it's impossible, using $n=10$ original samples, to detect that the standard deviation shrunk to $0.6,0.7,0.8,$ or $0.9$ of its original size.  Looking down the left column of the graphic and focusing on the vertical line at a p-value of $0.05,$ indeed we see that none of the curves exceeds $0.75$ (although the last one, for a practically infinite value of $m$, almost reaches $0.75$).

On the other hand, consider the column for `N.original:160`.  The sample size function says that when your original dataset has $n=160$ values, you need $m=15$ new values to identify a reduction to $\rho=0.6$ of the original SD, $m=29$ for $\rho=0.7,$ $m=87$ for $\rho=0.8,$ and will be unable to detect a reduction of $\rho=0.9$ with a power of $0.75.$  The graphic confirms this.  For instance, at the row `N.new:10` the upper red curve (for $\rho=0.6$) is below $0.75,$ but in the next row `N.new:20` the upper red curve has risen to exceed $0.75.$  Somewhere in between--where the new sample size is $15$--that red curve (if it were shown) would just barely exceed $0.75.$

In short, this figure shows you the chance of observing significant results for a range of possible effect sizes and a range of possible significance levels.

**It is well-known that F ratio statistics are sensitive to how heavy the tails of the underlying distributions might be.**  Here are the results of a comparable simulation for exponential distributions (which are both skewed and have heavier tails than the Normal).

[image: Figure 2]

This plot shows the F test has a tendency to detect differences much more frequently than one might expect: it is *too* powerful.  The blue curves (for no effect, $\rho=1$) are considerably higher than the uniform reference black curves: p-values tend to be lower more often than expected under Normality assumptions.  You can use a simulation like this both to adjust the power of the test and to determine a suitable sample size.  It can be a good way to assess how sensitive your experiment might be to departures from the Normality assumption.

---

#### Code

Here is the sample size function.  Its use was illustrated above.  All but one line are devoted to finding a range of solutions $m$ to search.  This is done by (a) verifying that a solution is possible and then (b) starting with a plausible upper limit and doubling that until it is larger than a solution.  At that point a basic univariate root finder `uniroot` is invoked to obtain a solution, which is extracted and rounded up to the next integer for return to the caller.

```
sample.size <- Vectorize(function(n, rho, alpha=0.05, beta=0.05) {
  f <- function(m) pf(rho^2 * qf(beta, m-1, n-1, lower.tail=FALSE), m-1, n-1) - alpha
  if (f(Inf) > 0)  return(NA_real_) # No solution
  
  upper <- ifelse(is.infinite(n), 2^20, n)
  while (upper < 2^30 & f(upper) > 0) upper <- 2*upper
  if (f(upper) > 0) return(NA_real_) # No solution
  
  sol = uniroot(f, c(2, upper))
  ceiling(sol$root)
}, c("n", "rho"))
```

Here is the code to generate the simulations.  It is controlled by changing the variables defined at the outset.  Notice the ability to specify the underlying random number generator (here, `rnorm`) without changing anything else.  It loops over the two sample sizes and the effect size, conducting `n.sim` experiments in each case (effectively a quadruple loop).  The p-values returned by those experiments are sorted so that their empirical cumulative distributions (ECDF) may readily be plotted. The output is managed with a rank-four array which is then unrolled into a data frame for visualizing the results using the `ggplot2` package.

```
n.original <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160, Inf)
n.new <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, Inf)
rho <- c(0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1)
alpha <- 0.05
n.sim <- 2000
rFUN <- rnorm         # Must be unit variance!
distribution.name <- "Normal"
#
# Simulate p-values.
#
system.time(
  sim <- sapply(n.original, function(n) {
    sapply(n.new, function(m) {
      sapply(rho, function(r) {
        sort(replicate(n.sim, {
          if (!is.infinite(n)) var.org <- var(rFUN(n)) else var.org <- 1
          if (!is.infinite(m)) var.new <- var(rFUN(m) * r) else var.new <- r^2
          f.ratio <- var.new / var.org
          pf(f.ratio, m-1, n-1)
        }))
      })
    })
  })
) # Takes about 10 seconds

Sim <- data.frame(P.value=c(sim),
          Iteration=rep(1:n.sim, length(rho) * length(n.new) * length(n.original)),
          Effect=factor(rep(rep(rho, each=n.sim), length(n.new) * length(n.original))),
          N.new=rep(rep(n.new, each=n.sim * length(rho)), length(n.original)),
          N.original=rep(n.original, each=n.sim * length(rho) * length(n.new)))
Sim$ECDF <- Sim$Iteration / n.sim

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Sim, aes(P.value, ECDF)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, color="Gray") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.75, color="Black") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.05) + 
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0, lwd=1.25, color="Black") + 
  geom_path(aes(color=Effect), size=1.25) + 
  facet_grid(N.new ~ N.original, scales="free_y", labeller="label_both") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 0.1)) + 
  xlab("P-value") + 
  ggtitle("Power Study For One-Sided SD Test", 
          paste(distribution.name, "distribution."))
```